# How to access Android Asset/RAW Folder in Background Service

Tags: android

I am currently working on a Push Notification feature for my client. I need to fetch text for the messages from a JSON-File which is located in the Android Asset/RAW folder.

Thus, I implemented it the following:

```
    private fun parseErrorCodes(): AssetErrors? {
    return try {
        val json = context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.errorcodes)
            .bufferedReader()
            .use(BufferedReader::readText)
        adapter.fromJson(json)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        logger.e("Failed to parse json: $e")
        null
    }
}
```

This piece of code will be called from a background service, which will handle the received push notification.

Everything works fine so far, but for Android 10 and later, for some reason the application cannot read the file when the app is in background, in foreground it works well though. This issue does not occur for Android 9 and below.

Does someone have an idea? Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Best regards
Robin

Comment: "the application cannot read the file when the app is in background" -- what precisely do you mean by this? For example, is your exception handler being executed? If so, if you change that logging code to log the stack trace, what is the stack trace?

Comment: Sorry, I was not precise enough. Basically this means that the InputStream from context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.errorcodes) is null. If the application is in foreground, the InputStream can be read and is not null.

Comment: Where is `context` coming from? This should be the `Service` (or the `Application` singleton) if you are calling this code from a `Service`.

Comment: context is injected via DI. In this case it is the applicationContext